# Conceptual data model for warehousing objects

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm student and new to databases. I must conceptualize a database model for warehousing video games using a [relational database management system](http://relational%20database%20management%20system) (MySQL).

Every objects in the warehouse have common fields (unique ID, picture url, price, weight, name, etc.).

Then, there is three object's types with their own specific fields :

1. Video Games
2. Consoles
3. Accessories
4. Controller
5. Hardware
6. Etc...

**What would be the best relation model to link a common object to its specific category, fields and sub-category?**

I know that there is [document-oriented database management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) that could do this easily, but I must work with MySQL.